# WPF Image source from constant

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, constants

I've got some icons that are resources in my project and I plan to use these icons for menu items and other things.

I've created a constants class to hold the locations of these icons in a central location rather than hardcoding them into each menu item etc.

E.g.

```
public const string IconName = "/Project;component/Icons/IconName.png";
```

If I hardcode this value into the Source property of an image in xaml it works fine. However, if I try to reference this constant then it fails.

E.g.

```
<Image Source="{x:Static pb:IconConstants.IconName}" Width="16" Height="16" />
```

It fails with this exception: "Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Source' to object of type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. ".

What is the difference between this and me just hardcoding the value? Is there a better way of referencing my constants in xaml?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that in first case (when you hardcode the path) the XAML parser will invoke a value converter (`ImageSourceConverter`) for the string you specify in the `Source` attribute to convert it to a value of type `ImageSource`. While in second case it expects that  value of your constant will already be of type `ImageSource`.

What you can do is you can put all the paths in a global `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="IconName">/Project;component/Icons/IconName.png</BitmapImage>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource IconName}" Width="16" Height="16" />
```

---

If you want to store the path constants in the code, you can have `Uri` objects as contants and set the `UriSource` property of `BitmapImage` to this URI:

```
public static readonly Uri IconName = new Uri("/Project;component/Icons/IconName.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="IconName" UriSource="{x:Static pb:IconConstants.IconName}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pavlo. I've been trying to get this working but I'm still getting an error "Cannot convert the string '/Project;component/Icons/IconName.png' into a 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' object.". Ideally it would have been good to store my constants as strings because I'm using them elsewhere for binding variables etc. I think I may just have to resort to hardcoding them in the meantime, reluctantly.

Comment: Thanks Pavlo. This will do the job! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to specify image as a resource in resource dictionary, there is a slight modification on top of what Pavlo mentioned. If you specify image path directly inline in the resource dictionary, for Windows 8 XAML it gives error

> "Error 1 Missing Content Property definition for Element 'BitmapImage'
>   to receive content '/Project;component/Icons/IconName.png'

To resolve it, you will have to specify path as UriSource.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <BitmapImage x:Key="ImageFollowOnFacebook" 
               UriSource="Assets/FollowOnFacebookImage.png"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```